# ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment

I am having this problem with this JavaScript code

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

```
const sendData = (path, data) =>{
    fetch(path, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"}),
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((res)=> res.json())
    .then(response => {
        processData(response);
    })
}
```

there seems to be an error in the fetch part

ive been trying to connect my signup form to firebase database search for solution for the entire day no results

Comment: seems like Firebase is throwing you an error page hence the HTML tokens.  The error must be in connecting the firebase rather than parsing json.

Comment: Add `catch` block for more debug info about real response.